# Hide categories from showing above a Post

Tags: posts, categories

Each Post on our blog has a subtitle on the right above the main content saying:

```
CATEGORY: <category 1>, <category 2>
```

How should someone that's unfamiliar with PHP, remove this entire block?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your theme, but if it's above every post, check for a file like content.php and if there are [post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats), there might also be content-video/gallery/whatever.php as well. Those are your files that are within the post loop. There should be a line of PHP that looks like one of these:

twentythirteen_entry_meta(); (using TwentyThirteen as a reference)

[the_category();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)

[get_the_category_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list)

There are more possibilities, but like I said, it depends on what theme you're using. The options above seem the most likely for a basic post displaying it's categories. If you're not sure, take a look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) and drop in a line of PHP that you think it is, and see if it gives you the definition. The Codex is pretty good at providing the results I need when I search. For tips on how to use the Codex, try this older [article of mine](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/03/searching-the-wordpress-codex-effectively/).

Or try this one from [WPMUDev](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/learn-how-to-search-the-wordpress-codex-more-effectively/).

Hope that helps and good luck!